# Sha1 hash is different in the Unity3d editor and on the iPhone6 device

Tags: ios, hash, unity-game-engine

I'm running the code

```
    var signatureBase = "CAAVRwZBSsH38BAJF7Ct1wUF3GRctdE9a0mHpmMZCa9UtlQMZBRaVC9dupKBuqlPp2BL7x12muSo0p9YZCnwajGBR7UJsNhIr9JWtnWJCaqf3k8azY50Ka87umbvd6mQKo19en0t5wCKRyPITCJtm4WP74MYa8XVNPyL1YABTwZB6xWsh37ZA0ISvDvoMVRfGLzkkWulZA8qqZC71b4kRWkBB";
    byte[] signatureBytes = new SHA1Managed ().ComputeHash (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (signatureBase));            
    SoapHexBinary shb = new SoapHexBinary( signatureBytes );        
    Debug.LogError (shb.ToString());
```

and getting different results:

```
device: 409E73E8A9971EB82435FE38556D37D2C888E22C

editor: 0CE1044C1D0CB90036811DD0C3B659A09FE5C2C3
```

Funny part is that difference had appeared several days ago. 
Before that, the hash from the editor was the same as on the device: server is expecting *0CE1044C1D0CB90036811DD0C3B659A09FE5C2C3* in the current case. I can connect via Editor, but Devices are failed to connect.

Tested devices: 2x iPhone6. Reproducible on both.

Upd: It seems to be a IL2CPP issue.

If to compile without it, i'm getting 0CE1044C1D0CB90036811DD0C3B659A09FE5C2C3.
But if to compile with IL2CPP enabled and run it on x64 compatible device, i'm getting 409E73E8A9971EB82435FE38556D37D2C888E22C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case solved.

On Unity 4.6.3, Sha1 is generating wrong result.

On Unity 4.6.2 it works fine on both device and editor.

UPD: fixed in 4.6.3p1.